# Поиск неизвестной переменной с помощью регулярных выражений (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!
Есть небольшой вопрос касательно регулярных выражений на питоне...

Преамбула:
Есть файл, содержащий информацию размером в N строк (кол-во постоянно меняется) типа:

```
...  
AAA1 BBB1 CCC1 DDD1 EEE1
AAA2 BBB2 CCC2 DDD2 EEE2
...
```

Так же есть всего лишь одна известная переменная (CCC1).

Фабула:

> Как найти с помощью регулярных выражений соседнюю от известной
>   переменную (DDD1)? Саму переменную ССС1 найти не составила труда, но
>   как теперь изъять следующую неизвестную переменную?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Ну вроде легко...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примитивный перебор с поиском:

```
data = ['AAA1 BBB1 CCC1 DDD1 EEE1', 'AAA2 BBB2 CCC2 DDD2 EEE2']

for line in data:
    items = line.split()
    if 'CCC1' not in items:
        continue

    i = items.index('CCC1')
    print(items[i + 1])  # DDD1
```

Answer (score 4):

Зачем регулярные выражения для такой примитивной задачи?

```
with open('file.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        tokens = line.split()
        d = tokens[3]  # Содержимое DDD
```

Answer (score 3):

Например можно так

```
import re

data = ['AAA1 BBB1 CCC1 DDD1 EEE1', 'AAA2 BBB2 CCC2 DDD2 EEE2']

for string in data:
    match = re.search('(?<=CCC1\s)(.*?)(?=\s)', string)

    print(match)
```

Результатом будет

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(15, 19), match='DDD1'>
```

Answer (score 2):

можно обойтись без циклов и без регулярных выражений - достаточно заменить перевод строки (`\n`) на пробел и разбить получившуюся строку по пробелам в спиcок:

```
data = """AAA1 BBB1 CCC1 DDD1 EEE1
       AAA2 BBB2 CCC2 DDD2 EEE2"""

lst = data.replace('\n', ' ').split()
print(lst)

print(lst[lst.index('CCC1')+1])
```

вывод:

```
['AAA1', 'BBB1', 'CCC1', 'DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA2', 'BBB2', 'CCC2', 'DDD2', 'EEE2']

DDD1
```